# Java: Date range check with open end date

Tags: java, date

What is most efficient way to compare date range in case of open end date i.e. optional end date? I want to compare effective date and optional end date given by user with any existing overlapping effective date and optional end date in database.If they overlap I want to display error message. Effective date is required and end date is optional.

Important:

effective and end date situation can be implemented in two general ways.

1) By having end date as DB column 
For example, Mortgage or saving account rate. The rate becomes effective at certain point of time and then it stays in effect till next rate becomes effective and ends previous rate's effect.At given point of time at least one record will be in effect.

2) By not having end date in database 
For example, Discount, coupoun, promotion or special offer. These all can become effective and end at certain point of time. It is possible that at given time no special offer or discount is running.

Scenario 1 is easy to implement. Every time you insert or edit the record you have to check there is no equivelent record in db with exact same effective date(and time).

Scenario 2 may have two further flavors.

2.1) End date is always required.(user entered or default with year 9999)
In such case, if you find any record that has (start1 <= end1 and start2 <= end2) then you have overlap.

2.2) End date is optional in that case null means positive infinity. User can enter end date or leave it blank.
This can be tricky to validate as more possible combination. You may need to generate query dynamically based on user has given end date or not

```
if(userEnd != null) {
  query.append(dbStart<=userEnd)
}
query.append(dbEnd is null || dbStart>=userStart && dbEnd>=userStart)
```

If this query finds any result then you are overlaping range. Going one step further if you have requirement to automatically end date previous record if previous record's end date is null then you may want to modify above query as below to pass validation.

```
if(userEnd != null) {
  query.append(dbStart<=userEnd)
}
query.append((dbEnd is null && dbStart>=userStart) || (dbStart>=userStart && dbEnd>=userStart))
```

Depending on other requirements you may need deleteDate to mark record invalid. Possible combination can be

Effective Date(Required) | Deleted Date (Optional)

OR

Effective Date(Required) | End Date(Required or Optional) | Deleted Date (Optional)

Comment: Are you trying to see if one date is inside a given range (that may be open-ended) or are you trying to see if one range is inside another range?

Answer (score 2):

I made a schematic image about a reference interval, which might be open ended (gradient), and a timespan to compare:

[image: schematic image]

- The 5 basic cases a-e are without open end. Let's consider the timespan to compare not being open ended in the beginning.

Let's further define, that no two dates matches exactly - maybe because they are measured in microseconds. It doesn't really matter, because you will just switch from < to <= or not, whatever you consider to be a valid assumption.

From the basic cases, we see, they always overlap, except the sample.end is < reference.start or sample.start > ref.end.

Who would have thought it is that easy?

- Well - let's see, what happens, if ref.end is open. Case a is not affected, but case e will overlap then too.

That was an easy one, wasn't it?

- Now we get difficult: What, if the sample is open ended? Case a will now overlap, but e not being affected.
- Hardcore experience: Both dates are open ended: Then an overlap occured.

Conclusion: If in doubt, do an image. Here it was inkscape.